# Apex Rollup summary trigger size() question

Tags: apex, trigger

I am trying to go through the following code posted by another individual:

```
trigger CountContactsnew on Contact (after insert, after delete, after undelete) {

    List<id> accIdList = new List<id>();
    if(Trigger.isInsert || Trigger.isUndelete){
        For(Contact con1 : Trigger.new){
            accIdList.add(con1.accountid);
        }
    }
    if(Trigger.isDelete){
        For(Contact con1 : Trigger.old){
            accIdList.add(con1.accountid);
        }
    }
    List<Account> accUpdateList = new List<Account>();
    For(Account acc : [SELECT Contact_Recs__c,(SELECT id FROM Contacts) FROM Account WHERE id =: accIdList]){
        acc.Contact_Recs__c = acc.Contacts.size();
        accUpdateList.add(acc);
    }
    try{
        update accUpdateList;
    }Catch(Exception e){
        System.debug('Exception :'+e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

However I am uncertain as to what the line:

```
acc.Contact_Recs__c = acc.Contacts.size();
```

accomplishes.  Could someone please let me know.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`acc.Contacts.size()` - returns the count of Contacts of Account under iteration.

This is a part of subquery. 
So when you have a query with inner join, another name for it is subquery:

```
SELECT Contact_Recs__c, (SELECT Id FROM Contacts) FROM Account
```

To access the list child contacts under an account, it can be accessed by `Account.Contacts`

and the statement indicates the its assigned to `Contact_Recs__c` field on Account.

---

**Added**: As suggested by Toby, adding the purpose of trigger.

Rollup summary fields are not supported if the objects don't have a master detail relationship. Relation between Account and Contact is hybrid and doesn't support rollups.

You can also use [Declarative Rollup Summary Tool](https://andyinthecloud.com/2014/02/09/new-release-spring14-declarative-rollup-summary-tool/), if you want to avoid writing code. Its a super awesome tool.

Comment: You may want to add a note about how you can't create roll-up fields on standard objects which is likely what this code is trying to replicate.

Comment: @Toby, In question it was simply mentioned about that line. good suggestion, will add it. thank you!

Comment: Glad to see you added a recommendation to use DLRS.

Comment: @RahulSharma so out of curiosity, and since I am new, how would this differ if it were for a SUM rather than COUNT

Comment: @dgelinas21, in that case you'd need to sum up the values from appropriate field from child to parent object.

Answer (score 5):

Well, the variable `acc` is an instance of an `Account` object.

In the query returning this account: `[SELECT Contact_Recs__c,(SELECT id FROM Contacts) FROM Account WHERE id =: accIdList]`, there is a nested query selecting the ids of the contacts related to this account: `(SELECT id FROM Contacts)`.

So the statement `acc.Contacts.size()` returns the size of the related contacts.

**Note**: The variable `Contact_Recs__c` must be of type Number.